# Keep matching pattern in shell parameter expansion

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I can remove a pattern in a bash variable using `${variable##pattern}` (leading) or `${variable%%pattern}` (trailing).

But I can't find a bash-only way to keep the pattern and throw the rest.

I know there are solutions using `sed`, `awk`, or `grep`, but I want to know if there is a reasonably efficient bash-only solution that I am overlooking?

PS: This isn't just an idle question. The initial problem is that I want to process files where the name contains a pattern (technically, `'[A-Z]+([A-Z])-[0-9][0-9]+([0-9])'`: capital letters followed by a dash and digits) and I want to use the same pattern to list the files and extract the matching string for further processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash you could also use regexes:

```
#!/bin/bash
re='[A-Z][A-Z]+-[0-9][0-9][0-9]+'
file=foo-BAR-1234.txt
if [[ $file =~ $re ]]; then
    echo "filename '$file' matches, matching part is '${BASH_REMATCH[0]}'"
fi
```

With `file=foo-BAR-1234.txt`, that would match the part `BAR-1234` and print accordingly. You could also use parenthesis in the regex to capture part of the pattern, they'd be available in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` etc.

Of course, note that the format for regexes is different than that of Bash/Ksh extended globs: instead of `+([abc])`, you need `[abc]+`, or `([abc])+`, the parenthesis being optional when the asterisk is applied to just that one bracket group. Same for `*` and `?`. Also, you could write e.g. `[0-9]{3,}` for three or more digits.

Answer (score 9):

```
${var%"${var##pattern}"}
${var#"${var%%pattern}"}
```

Example:

```
$ k='ab*10cd20ef*'
$ echo "${k%"${k##*[0-9]}"}"
ab*10cd20
$ echo "${k#"${k%%[0-9]*}"}"
10cd20ef*
```

Note the quotes are important to prevent the shell from interpreting
the expansions as a pattern. Try `echo "${k#${k%%[0-9]*}}"` to see it outputs an incorrect result.

Comment: Strictly speaking not a "`bash`-only" solution as it's portable to all `sh`-like shells :-)